# Ideal amount of piles to sort a stack of 250 cards (magic the gathering)

Tags: probability, sorting

I'm a hobbyist working on a mechanical sorting machine to sort magic the gathering cards. I'm by no means a mathematician though, and I was wondering if you all wouldn't mind helping me out with a practical math problem to determine the best route to go with my machine.

The average Magic The Gathering set of cards contains 250 unique cards. My machine will sort those cards alphabetically placing the cards into multiple piles repeatedly to filter the cards down into the correct position. My question is, how many piles would be needed to sort 250 cards with only three passes. Here is some further info more clarification of the question.

Example, a card passes through the scanner, and the computer determines  that the cards position in the alphabetized set is within the first 50 positions of the alphabetized set. 50 positions is %20 percent of a 250 card set, which I've chosen that number. It just seems like an easy place to start.

Then the next card passes through, and the scanner determines that the cards position is in the 3rd 50 positions of the alphabetized set (positions 101-150) so it places this in pile three. It keeps doing this until it has 250 cards broken down into 5 piles.

The cards are then scanned again for further refinement until they are in the correct order. So the question is, how many piles would make it possible to on average sort a 250 card set in 3 passes. I only chose 5 piles to illustrate the question, so I hope that's not confusing.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Kind Regards
Spencer

Comment: Have a look at [sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) first. What you are looking for could be an extension of [Merge Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).

Comment: Firstly, can you explain what information is available on each card, and whether you know at the beginning what the rank of all the cards is (i.e. like a standard deck of playing cards always has the same set of cards) and whether there are duplicates. Secondly, I suggest you post this as a puzzle on the puzzle stack exchange site.

Comment: @MonK - Thank you Monk. I will be sure to look at this

Comment: @PhilH - Phil, the available information on the card that is pertinent to this is the name of the card. The computer will have a sorted list of the cards in memory prior to the actual sort down so it will know in advance where each cards position in the set is.